# create a select from a javascript while loop

Tags: javascript

I have a while loop in javascript that is printing out values, now what I would like to do is print those out in a select field.

Here's my while loops:

```
i = 0
while i < audioInputDevices.length
  console.log 'audio input device: ', audioInputDevices[i].deviceId
  i++
i = 0
while i < videoInputDevices.length
  console.log 'video input device: ', videoInputDevices[i].deviceId
  i++
return
```

now I'd like to get these in two selects. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Wow, that's unusual Javascript... :P

Comment: Hi @Sebastian. This is not actually a place for *I have this...and want this* kind of question.

Comment: ibet you come from a C,C++ backgrown, you can use innerHTML to add dynamic html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you have in here is not JavaScript. Looks like kind of pseudo code to me. And yeah, you can do it this way:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  v = document.querySelector("#video");
  a = document.querySelector("#audio");
  
  audioInputDevices = ["Audio 1", "Audio 2"];
  videoInputDevices = ["Video 1", "Video 2", "Video 3"];
  
  for (i = 0; i < audioInputDevices.length; i++)
    a.innerHTML += '<option value="">' + audioInputDevices[i] + '</option>';
  
  for (i = 0; i < videoInputDevices.length; i++)
    v.innerHTML += '<option value="">' + videoInputDevices[i] + '</option>';
};
```

```html
<select id="video"></select>
<select id="audio"></select>
```

**Note:** I have added HTML and the array for you.

Comment: hey so this is working the only problem is that the options are going outside the select. So they're just popping up.

Comment: @SebastianJenningsAlmnes Excuse me, that's what a `<select>` tag is for? What exactly were you expecting?

Comment: no as in, they're not showing up inside the select tags. They're showing outside the <select></select>

Comment: @SebastianJenningsAlmnes That's how they are designed for. `:)` It is a system component. Are you new to Web Based work?